# Unable to use input widgets with QGraphicsItemGroup

Tags: c++, qt, qt6, qgraphicsitemgroup

I am trying to use inputs like QLineEdit and QSlider inside a QGraphicsItemGroup.

I am able to show them, and drag the group around, but unable to interact with them. It is clearly a problem with focus and events.

How do I use the group so that all objects move together, but switch focus on them when clicking specific items?

Minimal code example:

```cpp
QSlider* slider_ = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal);
QGraphicsProxyWidget* slider_item_ = new QGraphicsProxyWidget();
slider_item_->setWidget(slider_);

qreal sliderX = 0;
qreal sliderY = 0;
slider_item_->setPos(sliderX, sliderY);

QGraphicsItemGroup* tile_group_ = new QGraphicsItemGroup();
tile_group_->setFlags(QGraphicsItemGroup::ItemIsMovable | QGraphicsItemGroup::ItemIsFocusable | QGraphicsItemGroup::ItemIsSelectable);

tile_group_->addToGroup(slider_item_);

scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
scene->addItem(tile_group_);
```

I tried to pinpoint the issue. It only happens when the items are defined inside the group, so I need to handle the events manually somehow. I am on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Items that are stacked above can consume user events; your `outer_rect_` is probably the culprit, but we cannot tell you more unless you provide a valid [mre]. Note that the main purpose of QGraphicsItemGroup is similar to that of an item selection, it's not normally intended to create a group that has its own object hierarchy (and, possibly, a proper layout); use QGraphicsObject or QGraphicsWidget, along with QGraphicsLayouts.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Just found in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsitem-obsolete.html) QGraphicsItemGroup::setHandlesChildEvents(false); and it works but it is "strongly advise against" to use it. Does this help with finding the correct way to handle this? I'll edit with a reproducible example anyway!

Comment: You should normally not need that (also, that function is available for any QGraphicsItem type, not just groups), and the issue is probably somewhere else: as mentioned, it could be caused by overlapping items that consume events, or by the flags you set for the group, which take precedence over its contents. As said, you should probably not use QGraphicsItemGroup for that purpose.